# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;
 class stockbuysell{
    //Function to find the days of buying and selling stock for max profit.
    public static void main(String []args){
        int A[] = {100,180,260,310,40,535,695};
         ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> al = stockBuySell(A,7);
    }
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > stockBuySell(int A[], int n) {
        // code here
       // buy = 0;
        //sell = 1
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> al = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        int flag = 0;
        int idx = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
            if(i==n-1 && flag==1){
                al.get(idx).add(i);
                flag = 0;
            }
            if(flag == 0 && A[i]>A[i-1]){//
                al.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
                al.get(idx).add(i-1);
                flag = 1;
            }
            if(flag == 1 && A[i]<A[i-1]){//
                al.get(idx).add(i-1);
                flag = 0;
                idx++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){
            System.out.println(al.get(i).get(0)+" "+al.get(i).get(1));
        }
        return al;
    }
}
```

I don't know where I get an error. It compiled successfully, while running it shows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
        at stockbuysell.stockBuySell(stockBuySell.java:32)
        at stockbuysell.main(stockBuySell.java:6)
```

Comment: I think it would be good for you, if you debug it. That will help you to understand it better. And what you are trying to do here in code?

Comment: `al.get(i).get(0)` is the culprit. Visually, that's line 32 of what you posted. The ith element of al is an empty array. The 3 if statements in the for loop don't guarantee anything is added.

Comment: Not sure what your algorithm does, but the problem is the last time through the loop. It sets flag=0 but does not increment `idx`, and immediately after it will add a new element to the arraylist, but idx still references the previous entry, and nothing is added to the last arraylist

Comment: Subtract one unit from `al.size()` in your last for loop: `for(int i=0;i<al.size()-1;i++)...`

Answer (score 0):

if you run this code

System.out.println(arrayListName.get(arrayListName.size()-1));

> It compiled successfully, while running it shows:  Exception in thread
> "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

When array list is empty and you search value from it in that way you get error.
But if you check does your array list is empty. When array list have at least one element in it, run code and you get your value - no compiler error.

```
        public static void functionNameHere(){
    if (!arrayListName.isEmpty() ){
            //execute code
            System.out.println(arrayListName.get(arrayListName.size()-1));
            }       
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your arraylist is having some empty list and if you access it, it will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException.

[image: Empty]

Always check if data is present in that index before accessing it.

Comment: Array is initialized in the code, it's length is not matching in  System.out.println(al.get(i).get(0)+" "+al.get(i).get(1));. Here get(0) and get(1) are breaking in code.

Comment: It is always advised not to hardcode any index values for accessing and even if you must, you should check if the value is present before accessing it.

Comment: Your outer arraylist is initialized in the code, but you have added an arrayList that is still empty when you try to read it. I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do, but I would advise stepping through it in a debugger to figure out where it's not behaving the way you expect. I would also suggest using a boolean for "flag" instead of alternating between 1 and 0. This makes the code easier to read and understand. More descriptive variable names would be helpful, too, if you're going to ask for help.